why the y values are not changed by reflection over y axis?
If we reflect $\sqrt{x}$ over y axis by changing the sign of input: $\sqrt{-x}$ . For the same domain as for $\sqrt{x}$ , the output of $\sqrt{-x}$ is imaginary numbers, which can't be plotted on a cartesian plane. Then how come we just use the same y values from the range of $\sqrt{x}$ ? Shouldn't we calculate and plot the y values based on the changed x values?
This question might sound very silly, but I can't understand the intuition behind it. Thank you in advance.

Notice  that these transformations can affect the function’s domain and range. In this case, the new domain should be $(-\infty,0]$.

@CroCo As far as I know, there are mainly the following types of graph transformation: 1) Vertical/ Horizontal Shift 2) Vertical/ Horizontal Stretch/ Compression 3) Reflection. Now which one of these transformations can affect the function's domain and range? Because I checked for Vertical/ Horizontal Stretch/ Compression, and it doesn't affect the domain or range of a function. Is this true?

How did you check for "Vertical/ Horizontal Stretch/ Compression"? They certainly can affect domain or range of a function.

"Shouldn't we calculate and plot the y values based on the changed x values?"- We do, and the $y$-values turn out to be the same as before.
$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{-(-x)}$

@DavidK I applied it on basic functions like, $X^2$, $X^3$, $\sqrt{x}$, etc.

Those functions all have domains and ranges like $(-\infty,\infty)$ or $[0,\infty)$ -- precisely the kinds of domain and range that are not affected by stretch along an axis. Try $y = \arcsin x$ for something different.


Points/objects reflected over the y axis with opposite-signed x coordinates (e.g. -1 and 1) have the same y coordinates.

Nice and concise!

"If we reflect $\sqrt{x}$ over y axis" we're really dealing with reflection of the graph of the equation $y = \sqrt x$ over the $y$ axis (which is why we call it "reflection").
What do you think the reflection of the graph should look like? What are the projections of the graph onto the $x$ and $y$ axes? Those are the domain and range of the reflected function.
Generally, when you reflect a graph across an axis, if you consider the graph plus its projections onto the axes as a single object, the entire object gets reflected, including the parts that were projections onto axes.
So when you reflect any function across the $y$ axis, the projection onto the $x$ axis (which gives the domain) is reflected across the $y$ axis and so is the projection onto the $y$ axis (which gives the range),
but reflecting something that's already on the $y$ axis across the $y$ axis doesn't change the object at all. So the range is always unchanged.
What you really need to do here is convince yourself that the graph of
$y = \sqrt{-x}$ really is just a reflection of the graph of $y = \sqrt{x}$ across the $y$ axis.
Try a few values of $x$ and see what you find.
